# float prints out negative 0 in c

Tags: c, floating-point

I am reading characters over a rs-232 serial line from a meter. Due to the check sum byte being correct, I am 100 percent sure the values are all correct. One thing that confuses me is that 4 bytes that represent a pressure value returns -0.000000. That negative sign doesn't seem right at all. Here's an extracted example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char cmd[] = {
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};

float float_byte_join(unsigned char *from, int size)
{
    float value;
    value = 0;
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)&value;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; i++, j--) {
        p[j] = *from;
        ++from;
    }
        printf("value is %f\n", value);
    return value;
}

int main(void)
{
  float_byte_join(cmd, 4);
  return 0;
}

// result:
value is -0.000000
```

Any idea why this prints -0.000000 rather than 0.000000? Do those 4 characters really represent a negative number? I thought two's complement has no such thing as a negative 0.

Comment: Yes. That's the representation of negative zero as a 32-bit binary float. Two's complement doesn't have negative zero, but you're not dealing with two's complement.

Comment: Note: A -0.0 from a sensor may have special meaning or subtle meaning.  Say the pressure _reports_ in thousandths 0.001, but _measures_ to a bit higher precision.  Values like +0.0002 and -0.0002, without a negative zero would both round to 0.000.  It may be important to know if pressure is + or -.   Reading -0.000 may indicate a _slow_ leak.  Use `int signbit(real-floating)` macro to whether the sign of its argument value is negative as mathematically -0.0 and +0.0 compare the same using ==, >, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two's complement *integers* have no negative zero, but IEEE floating point values *do* have a negative zero, and it is encoded as `80 00 00 00` (hex, big-endian, single-precision).  So if that really is the byte sequence you are getting from your device, then that is the correct result.

This and many other oddities of IEEE floating point are explained and justified in the paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf), which, since you are a computer scientist, you should read.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks, but that seems like a URL likely not to remain good into the indefinite future.  (As does mine, alas, but I give it better odds anyway.)

Comment: If you want to eliminate the possibility of -0, just add 0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You set the sign bit( most significant bit ) to 1 which specifies a negative number, change it to 0.

```
unsigned char cmd[] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

(but anyway: -0.0f == 0.0f )